# Why can't scala compile a Long switch statement to a tableswitch

Tags: scala, switch-statement

When I do

```
val oldId :Long  = 123;

val i = 1
val newId = (oldId: @switch) match {
  case 1  => 1234
  case 2  => 5678
  case 3  => 1122
  case 4  => 3344
}
```

I get compiler warning

```
[ant:scalac] mycode.scala:25: warning: could not emit switch for @switch annotated match
[ant:scalac]     val newId = (oldId: @switch) match {
[ant:scalac]                          ^
[ant:scalac] one warning found
```

However if I instead use the following code

```
val oldId :Int  = 123;

val i = 1
val newId = (oldId: @switch) match {
  case 1  => 1234
  case 2  => 5678
  case 3  => 1122
  case 4  => 3344
}
```

then the compiler doesn't give me a warning.  Why is it not possible to use a `Long` and get a `tableswitch`?

Comment: The natural question is why doesn't the compiler report why. The doc does warn that no warning is emitted for two cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is it not possible to use a Long and get a tableswitch?

Because the JVM [supports @tableswitch on `int` and types convertable to `int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10):

> The Java Virtual Machine's tableswitch and lookupswitch instructions operate only on int data. Because operations on byte, char, or short values are internally promoted to int, a switch whose expression evaluates to one of those types is compiled as though it evaluated to type int

Thus you get a compile time warning because `long` is not implicitly convertible to an `int`.

Comment: Hmm, do you know why this is the case?  I would guess something to do with implementing the operation efficiently with a 32 bit processor and wanting to maintain the backwards capability.  Maybe?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas This is the case because Java doesn't support `long` in a switch case at all. A switch value must be either `byte`, `char`, `short` (which are all convertible to `int`) or `string` (added in java 7 and has a [special case of a tableswitch](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JavaCodeToByteCode_PartOne.html)) because switch statements will be either converted to tableswitches or lookuptables, which only support `int` at the bytecode level.